# Download issue with BinaryFileResponse and APP_ENV=prod

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm having a file downloading issue with Symfony 4 using `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse`.

When switching from `APP_ENV=dev` to `APP_ENV=prod` (in local for instance and having cleared cache), only response headers are received on the browser (note the content length):

```
Date: Thu, 27 Sep 2018 07:47:17 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, private
Last-Modified: Thu, 27 Sep 2018 07:47:22 GMT
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=kJKpFb
Content-Length: 0
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

The code used to perform the download:

```php
$response = new BinaryFileResponse($file->getPathname());
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
$response->setContentDisposition(
    ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_INLINE,
    $file->getFilename()
);

return $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

Symfony v3.2 introduced `File controller helper`. Same syntax should work in 4.x [example 1](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-file-controller-helper) [example 2](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/329/how-to-send-a-file-as-response-from-a-controller-in-symfony-3)

Comment: I know how to fix the issue; adding `.pdf` to the end of the temporary file do the trick for instance. But the problem seems not to lie here since it occurs when changing the `APP_ENV` from `dev` to `prod`. Why the heck? I'd like to understand.